# How the two length are equal?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have understood that EDCF is a rhombus because of the conditions given. But I have got a [solution for this problem](http://mathholic.weebly.com/q--a/can-you-prove-that-the-area-of-the-triangle-abe-is-equal-to-the-area-of-the-quadrilateral-efcd) they said that  joining D and F , DF is equal to BC. How can this be true?

Comment: They do not say that DF=CD there. But anyway, they have lots of other misprints (e.g., they claim that CB=CE (????)). Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [solution of the problem](http://mathholic.weebly.com/q--a/can-you-prove-that-the-area-of-the-triangle-abe-is-equal-to-the-area-of-the-quadrilateral-efcd) said that $DF = CB$, which is useful and true.
It's also "obvious", but in this context I can see that's not really satisfactory.

You could observe that $DF$ is one of the diagonals of a rhombus, 
so it's perpendicular to the other diagonal, $CE$; 
and $BC$ is also perpendicular to $CE$, leading to the
conclusions that $DF$ is parallel to $BC$ and that $BCDF$ is a parallelogram,
and so $DF = CB$ (opposite sides of a parallelogram).
There are surely other ways to derive the same fact, however, so I'm not sure exactly
which line of reasoning the posted solution expects you to apply.

I also noticed that the solution said that $CB = CE$, 
which does not follow from the other information provided, 
but then there was no use of this "fact". 
I think this was likely a typographic error, where the intention was to state that $CB = AE$ 
(which is true and was implicitly used in the solution).

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question.  I wanted to ask that how **DF is equal to BC**.

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited the answer, too, as I think you have a good point there.